# Div is not displaying vertically aligned inside another div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to display video full screen when user starts the application and when user presses 'm', Video div size should be reduced and need to display a div under the video and text inside the div. The text should be horizontally and vertically aligned inside the div. I used display: table-cell but it is not working. Below is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>VOD</title>
            <script src='js/index.js'></script>
            <style>
                html, body
                {
                    height:100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    background-color: #2F4F4F;
                }

                #header {
                    position: fixed;
                    left: 0px;
                    top: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 75px;
                    background-color: black;
                    color: white;
                    padding-left: 75px;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                }

                #hdiv {
                    position: fixed;
                    left: 75px;
                    top: 300px;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 376px;
                    display: table;
                    box-shadow: inset 7px 0 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7), inset -7px 0 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
                }

                #htxtdiv {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 50px;
                    color: white;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    text-align: center;
                }

                #vid.full {
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    z-index: 3;
                    min-width: 100%;
                    min-height: 100%;
                    width: auto;
                    height: auto;
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                #vid.pip {
                    position: fixed;
                    left: 75px;
                    top: 75px;
                    width: 376px;
                    height: 205px;
                    background-color:black;
                    border-left: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
                    border-right: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
                    z-index: 3;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id='maindiv' style='display:none'>
                <div id='header'>
                    <h2>DVR</h2>
                </div>
                <div id='hdiv'>
                    <div id='htxtdiv'>
                        <h3>Cloud DVR Recordings</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <video id='vid' src='textMotion.mp4'class='full' autoplay></video>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function displayMenu() {
    // If already menu is visible, hide it
    let vid = document.getElementById('vid');
    let mdiv = document.getElementById('maindiv');

    if(vid.classList.contains('pip') == true) {
        mdiv.style.display = 'none';
        vid.classList.add('full');
        vid.classList.remove('pip');
        return;
    }

    mdiv.style.display = 'block';
    vid.classList.add('pip');
    vid.classList.remove('full');
}

function processKeyPress(e) {
    console.log('received keyEvent : ' + e.keyCode);
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;

    // Menu button or key 'm'
    if((keyCode == 77) || (keyCode == 462)) {
        displayMenu();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', processKeyPress);
```

I am using 'display: table' for outer div(hdiv) and 'display: table-cell' for inner div (htxtdiv). Even though 'Cloud DVR Recordings' text is horizontally centered, it is not vertically centered.

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. 'height: 100%' in hdiv is the culprit. hdiv is not starting from top: 0. It is starting from top : 300px. So height shouldn't be 100%. It should be set to window.innerHeight - 300. I set the height through javascript. Once we set the height like this, either table-cell approach or flex box approach should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox instead of table-cell,

```
#hdiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

so just add these and remove `display: table-cell` and remove everything from `#htxtdiv` except the colors

Comment: Not working. Same result. Removed everything from htxtdiv except font and color. Added display: flex, align-items: center and justify-content: center to hdiv. Do I need to add anything to htxtdiv?